# Parse Quartz cron expression with Croniter

Tags: python, cron, quartz-scheduler

This code:

```
starting_point = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
cron = croniter.croniter('44 5 19 ? * WED,THU,FRI *', starting_point)
cron.get_next(datetime.datetime)
```

Results in:

> croniter.croniter.CroniterBadCronError: Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iterator expression.

But when using https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html, the same expression results in

> At 19:05:44pm, on every Wednesday, Thursday and Friday, every month

How to parse this cron expression with croniter?

Comment: What did you intend the `?` and the two `*` to stand for, respectively?

Comment: *"Why so?"* - because you have specified 7 columns, not 5 or 6 as required.

Comment: How to have the same result as here:
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you are referring to uses the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which supports the fields

```
Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Day Of Month, Month, Day Of Week, Year
```

but with [croniter](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter) the `Seconds` field is optional and apparently is expected at the last position (I did not find this to be particularly well documented and have concluded this through experimentation):

```
Minutes, Hours, Day Of Month, Day Of Week, Seconds
```

Furthermore it does not seem to support the `?` wildcard.

So an equivalent expression seems to be

```
5 19 * * WED,THU,FRI 44
```

Demo:

```
>>> import croniter
>>> import datetime
>>> c = croniter.croniter('5 19 * * WED,THU,FRI 44')
>>> print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(next(c)))
2021-04-23 19:05:44
>>> print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(next(c)))
2021-04-28 19:05:44
>>> print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(next(c)))
2021-04-29 19:05:44
```