# Which is the best python package to parse the Quartz-style cron expression?

Tags: python, cron, quartz-scheduler

Recently, I need to process the Quartz-style cron expression by Python. However, I try many kinds of python packages, and cannot find any one which can fully support quartz cron expression.

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233513/parse-quartz-cron-expression-with-croniter). Croniter is a good package, but cannot meet my requirement. For example, it fails to parse `7 0 15 6 */1 ?`.

My question is what is the best python package that truly support quartz cron expression. Thank you.